# Google (Yahoo, Bing) Meta Description not correct

Tags: html, search, meta-tags

I wonder whether you chaps can see why the Google results description for this website:

[www.eastnorlandrovershow.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20120117165504/http://www.eastnorlandrovershow.com/)

Is showing as:

[image: Google Search Result for Eastnor Land Rover Show]

When the Meta Description says:

```
<meta name="Description" content="Eastnor Land Rover Show, it's time to welcome you and the best 4x4 by far to it's ancestral home, Eastnor Castle. Taking place over 25th-26th August 2012">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not usually use the meta tag for its description, it will usually take the some text from within the body tag.

> campingpic2a. item1. Privacy Policy - Terms and Conditions

Areas of code google is taking your text from:

```
<img src="Resources/campingpic2a.jpeg" border=0 width=256 height=110
alt="campingpic2a" style="float:left">
```

```
<div id="item9" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:818px; width:93px; height:15px; z-index:2; overflow:visible">
    <p class="f-lp"><span class="style3"><strong><span class="style11"><a href="privacypolicy.html"><span class="style30" style="text-decoration:underline">Privacy Policy</span></a></span></strong></span></p>
</div>
<div id="item9a" style="position:absolute; left:108px; top:818px; width:109px; height:13px; z-index:3; overflow:visible">
    <p class="f-lp"><span class="style3"><strong><span class="style11"><a href="termsandconditio.html"><span class="style30" style="text-decoration:underline">Terms and Conditions</span></a></span></strong></span></p>
</div>
```

The reason this is being used as google's description is because your source only only contains footer links and the alt for your image maps main image.

Maintaining a description meta tag is important, just not for google.

If you want google to be able to read your content easily you need to put your headers in h tags, content in p tags and menus in lists.

Comment: Makes sense, this is not my site - I'm asking on behalf of someone who is using Freeway on a Mac, I guess they're pretty much stuck with it unless I grab the HTML and change it.

Comment: Right, I've gone and grabbed a copy of the website to look at the HTML. I see exactly what you mean now - how can Freeway get away with creating code like this? It's shockingly bad.

Comment: Its entirely to do with having designers who don't want to learn HMTL, or the basics of SEO, and exploiting that reluctance for cash. In the short term it seems like a good idea, the designer doesn't need to pay the developer every time they want a change/make a new website. In the long run the clients will eventually find out they have a sub standard product and the designer will lose the business.